# Add PercentDoneByStoryPoint to HTML DIV

Tags: rally, confluence

In the 1.x version of the Rally SDK I was able to query and assign to an HTML DIV with a query like the following:

```
var querySI48 = { 
  type : 'portfolioitem',
  query:'(Name = "Q3 2015 Release (2.8.0)")',
  key : 'SI48Key',
  fetch: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount'
};
```

And assign it to a DIV like this:

```
var WS215 = document.getElementById("WS215");
WS215.innerHTML = "<h2>" + pisInfo + "%</h2>";
```

How can I assign the PercentDoneByStoryPoint to a DIV with the 2.X SDK?  I'm creating a dashboard in Confluence that contains Rally data.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the following should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('Rally.example.App', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {

                    var me = this;

                    var divTemplateString = "<h2>{0}: Percent Done by Story Count = {1}</h2>";

                    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
                        fetch: true,
                        autoLoad: true,
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'FormattedID',
                                value: 'F15'
                            }
                        ],
                        listeners: {
                            load: function(store, data, success) {
                                var formattedID = data[0].get('FormattedID');
                                var pctDoneByStoryCount = data[0].get('PercentDoneByStoryCount');
                                var divHTML = Ext.String.format(divTemplateString, formattedID, pctDoneByStoryCount);
                                var div = Ext.get('F15');
                                me.add({
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    html: divHTML,
                                    renderTo: div
                                });             
                            }
                        },                      
                    });
                }
            });


            Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.App', {
              name: 'Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="F15"</div>
</body>
</html>
```